# How to retrieve photo previews in app.net

Tags: image, preview

When I have an app.net url like `https://photos.app.net/5269262/1` - how can I retrieve the image thumbnail of the post?

Running a curl on above url shows a redirect

```
bash-3.2$ curl -i https://photos.app.net/5269262/1
HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Location: https://alpha.app.net/pfleidi/post/5269262/photo/1
```

Following this gives a html page that contains the image in a form of

```
img src='https://files.app.net/1/60621/aWBTKTYxzYZTqnkESkwx475u_ShTwEOiezzBjM3-ZzVBjq_6rzno42oMw9LxS5VH0WQEgoxWegIDKJo0eRDAc-uwTcOTaGYobfqx19vMOOMiyh2M3IMe6sDNkcQWPZPeE0PjIve4Vy0YFCM8MsHWbYYA2DFNKMdyNUnwmB2KuECjHqe0-Y9_ODD1pnFSOsOjH' data-full-width='2048' data-full-height='1536'
```

Inside a larger block of `<div>`tags.

The files api in app.net allows to [retrieve thumbnails](http://developers.app.net/docs/resources/file/#derived-files) but I somehow don't get the link between those endpoints and above urls.

Comment: The app.net platform no longer exists. I suggest closing and possibly deleting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photos.app.net is just a simple redirecter. It is not part of the API proper. In order to get the thumbnail, you will need to fetch the file directly using the file fetch endpoint and the file id (http://developers.app.net/docs/resources/file/lookup/#retrieve-a-file) or fetch the post that the file is included in and examine the oembed annotation.

In this case, you are talking about post id 5269262 and the URL to fetch that post with the annotation is https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/5269262?include_annotations=1 and if you examine the resulting json document you will see the thumbnail_url.

Comment: As an aside, the photos.app.net endpoint is really just a small server script that looks at the post id and the number afterwards, fetches the post from the app.net API, and returns an HTTP redirect to the URL. You could write your own equivalent if you so desired.

Comment: I saw that the photos.app.net is only a simple redirect -- but that is the starting point :) That url that you just posted seems to be the missing link I am looking for - Will probably check this on the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake I want to post the final solution for me here (in Java) -- it builds on the good and accepted answer of Jonathon Duerig :

```
private static String getAppNetPreviewUrl(String url) {

    Pattern photosPattern = Pattern.compile(".*photos.app.net/([0-9]+)/.*");
    Matcher m = photosPattern.matcher(url);
    if (!m.matches()) {
        return null;
    }
    String id = m.group(1);

    String streamUrl = "https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/" 
         + id + "?include_annotations=1";

    // Now that we have the posting url, we can get it and parse 
    // for the thumbnail
    BufferedReader br = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(streamUrl).openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
        urlConnection.connect();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        urlConnection.disconnect();

        // Parse the obtained json
        JSONObject post = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        JSONObject data = post.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray annotations = data.getJSONArray("annotations");
        JSONObject annotationValue = annotations.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject value = annotationValue.getJSONObject("value");
        String finalUrl = value.getString("thumbnail_large_url");

        return finalUrl;
    } .......
```